# How to sum distinct values of a field in a MongoDB collection (utilizing mongoose)

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, aggregation-framework

Imagine I had a collection called *journals* containing documents like the following:

```
{
  "article": "id1",
  "d": 2
},
{
  "article": "id1",
  "d": 2
},
{
  "article": "id1",
  "d": 3
},
{
  "article": "id2",
  "d": 2
},
...
```

Where *d* is kind of a switch and *article* is a reference. Now I want to have a result like the following:

```
[
  {
    "_id": "id1",
    "total": 3,
    "d2": 2,
    "d3": 1
  },
  {
    "_id": "id2",
    "total": 1,
    "d2": 1,
    "d3": 0
  }
]
```

I'm using *mongoose* and have a model called *Journal*. What I've got so far is…

```
Journal.aggregate(
  { $project: {
    articleId: 1,
    depth2 : { $gte:['$d', 2] },
    depth3 : { $eq:['$d', 3] }
  }},
  { $group: {
      _id: '$article',
      total: { $sum: 1 },
      d2: { $sum: '$depth2'},
      d3: { $sum: '$depth3'}
    }
  },
  function (err, journal) {
    console.log(journal);
  }
);
```

which results in:

```
[
  {
    "_id": "id1",
    "total": 3,
    "d2": 0,
    "d3": 0
  },
  {
    "_id": "id2",
    "total": 1,
    "d2": 0,
    "d3": 0
  }
]
```

Obviously the error here is that `$eq:['$d', 3]` is not summed up because that results in a boolean.

**So is there a better expression that projects the new depth2 and depth3 fields to `1`or `0` instead of `true` or `false`?**
**Or is there a complete and better approach? :)**

I'd like to avoid making 3 queries and prepending a matching phase like `{ $match: { d: 2 } }`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`$cond`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/cond/#exp._S_cond) to convert a boolean to a numerical value, but you've also got a `$gte` where it seems an `$eq` should be and your docs use `article` while your code uses `articleId`:

```
Journal.aggregate([
  { $project: {
    article: 1,
    depth2 : { $cond: [{$eq: ['$d', 2]}, 1, 0] },
    depth3 : { $cond: [{$eq: ['$d', 3]}, 1, 0] }
  }},
  { $group: {
      _id: '$article',
      total: { $sum: 1 },
      d2: { $sum: '$depth2'},
      d3: { $sum: '$depth3'}
    }
  }
]);
```

Output:

```
{
    "result" : [ 
        {
            "_id" : "id2",
            "total" : 1,
            "d2" : 1,
            "d3" : 0
        }, 
        {
            "_id" : "id1",
            "total" : 3,
            "d2" : 2,
            "d3" : 1
        }
    ],
    "ok" : 1
}
```

Comment: This is like Christmas, thanks a lot! And yes, you're right about the articleId, that happened in the process of simplifying the example. As for the $gte, that's on purpose as it fits my needs. So *d* is not exactly a switch, I was lying about that, but for the matter of asking here on SO it was as best described as I could :)
Again, thanks for your time!