# Count occurrences of duplicate values

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, aggregation-framework, mlab

How do I structure my MongooseJS/MongoDB query to get total duplicates/occurrences of a particular field value? Aka: The total documents with `custID` of `some value` for all custIDs

I can do this manually in command line:

`db.tapwiser.find({"custID" : "12345"}, {}, {}).count();`

Outputs: 1

`db.tapwiser.find({"custID" : "6789"}, {}, {}).count();`

Outputs: 4

---

I found this resource:

[How to sum distinct values of a field in a MongoDB collection (utilizing mongoose)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27213284/how-to-sum-distinct-values-of-a-field-in-a-mongodb-collection-utilizing-mongoos)

But it requires that I specify the unique fields I want to sum.

In this case, I want to loop through all documents, sum the occurrences of each.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

All you need to do is [`$group`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/#pipe._S_group) your documents by `custID` and use the [`$sum`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/sum/#grp._S_sum) accumulator operator to return "count" for each group.

```js
db.tapwiser.aggregate(
    [ 
        { "$group":  { "_id": "$custID", "count": { "$sum": 1 } } }
    ],  function(err, results) {
            // Do something with the results
        }
)
```

Comment: Is there a way to filter out the items where `count` is 1, thus leaving only the duplicates in the output? Can't quite wrap my head around the aggregation framework and what it can and can't do.

Comment: Hi @VioletGiraffe, To select on duplicates, you need to finish the aggregation pipeline with a `$match` stage i.e you need to add `{$match: {"count": {"$gte": 2}}}` after the `$group` stage.
I think the aggregation framework is MongoDB swiss army knife, you can do many things like  [first order derivative](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38957649/compute-first-order-derivative-with-mongodb-aggregation-framework)

Comment: Much appreciated!