# Compute first order derivative with MongoDB aggregation framework

Tags: python, mongodb, mapreduce, pymongo, aggregation-framework

Is it possible to calculate a first order derivative using the aggregate framework?

For example, I have the data :

```
{time_series : [10,20,40,70,110]}
```

I'm trying to obtain an output like:

```
{derivative : [10,20,30,40]}
```

Comment: Is there are reason you're wanting to do this within the aggregation framework vs. using a robust python library implementation?

Comment: @JohnnyHK - Can you give me an example of a python library implementation?

My current workaround is to fetch all the fields using pymongo, and doing the derivative in python. It turns out to be quite slow (limited by network bandwidth?) which made me look around for alternatives.

Comment: @JohnnyHK I think the aggregation framework is the best option here. Even faster than [`numpy.diff`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.diff.html). I added benchmark test result to my answer

Comment: @Styvane Don't get me wrong, I was the first person to upvote both answers here because they're great, but the "best" option is about more than performance. A well tested library call is simpler/easier to understand/cleaner than a complex aggregate pipeline.

Comment: @JohnnyHK I can't agree more. Not everything in programming is about performance. It is just a shame that MongoDB  doesn't provide an operator for this.  Btw I lost track of the curly brace many times when I was writing.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
db.collection.aggregate(
    [
      {
        "$addFields": {
          "indexes": {
            "$range": [
              0,
              {
                "$size": "$time_series"
              }
            ]
          },
          "reversedSeries": {
            "$reverseArray": "$time_series"
          }
        }
      },
      {
        "$project": {
          "derivatives": {
            "$reverseArray": {
              "$slice": [
                {
                  "$map": {
                    "input": {
                      "$zip": {
                        "inputs": [
                          "$reversedSeries",
                          "$indexes"
                        ]
                      }
                    },
                    "in": {
                      "$subtract": [
                        {
                          "$arrayElemAt": [
                            "$$this",
                            0
                          ]
                        },
                        {
                          "$arrayElemAt": [
                            "$reversedSeries",
                            {
                              "$add": [
                                {
                                  "$arrayElemAt": [
                                    "$$this",
                                    1
                                  ]
                                },
                                1
                              ]
                            }
                          ]
                        }
                      ]
                    }
                  }
                },
                {
                  "$subtract": [
                    {
                      "$size": "$time_series"
                    },
                    1
                  ]
                }
              ]
            }
          },
          "time_series": 1
        }
      }
    ]
)
```

We can use the pipeline above in version 3.4+ to do this.
In the pipeline, we use the [`$addFields`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/addFields) pipeline stage. operator to add the array of the "time_series"'s elements index to do document, we also reversed the time series array and add it to the document using respectively the [`$range`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/range/) and [`$reverseArray`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/reverseArray) operators

We reversed the array here because the element at position `p` in the array is always greater than the element at position `p+1` which means that `[p] - [p+1] < 0` and we do not want to use the [`$multiply`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/multiply) here.(see pipeline for version 3.2)

Next we `$zipped` the time series data with the indexes array and applied a [`substract`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/subtract) expression to the resulted array using the `$map` operator.

We then `$slice` the result to discard the `null/None` value from the array and re-reversed the result.

---

In 3.2 we can use the [`$unwind`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/) operator to *unwind* our array and include the index of each element in the array by specifying a document as operand instead of the traditional "path" prefixed by *$*.

Next in the pipeline, we need to [`$group`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/) our documents and use the [`$push`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/push/) accumulator operator to return an array of sub-documents that look like this:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("57c11ddbe860bd0b5df6bc64"),
    "time_series" : [
        { "value" : 10, "index" : NumberLong(0) },
        { "value" : 20, "index" : NumberLong(1) },
        { "value" : 40, "index" : NumberLong(2) },
        { "value" : 70, "index" : NumberLong(3) },
        { "value" : 110, "index" : NumberLong(4) }
    ]
}
```

---

Finally comes the [`$project`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/project) stage. In this stage, we need to use the [`$map`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/map/) operator to apply a series of expression to each element in the the newly computed array in the `$group` stage.

Here is what is going on inside the `$map` (see `$map` as a for loop) **in** expression:

For each subdocument, we assign the *value* field to a variable using the [`$let`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/let) variable operator. We then subtract it value from the value of the "value" field of the next element in the array.

Since the next element in the array is the element at the current index plus one, all we need is the help of the [`$arrayElemAt`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/arrayElemAt) operator and a simple [`$add`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/add)ition of the current element's index and `1`.

The [`$subtract`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/subtract) expression return a negative value so we need to multiply the value by `-1` using the [`$multiply`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/multiply) operator.

We also need to [`$filter`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/filter) the resulted array because it the last element is `None` or `null`. The reason is that when the current element is the last element, `$subtract` return `None` because the index of the next element equal the size of the array.

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    "$unwind": {
      "path": "$time_series",
      "includeArrayIndex": "index"
    }
  },
  {
    "$group": {
      "_id": "$_id",
      "time_series": {
        "$push": {
          "value": "$time_series",
          "index": "$index"
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$project": {
      "time_series": {
        "$filter": {
          "input": {
            "$map": {
              "input": "$time_series",
              "as": "el",
              "in": {
                "$multiply": [
                  {
                    "$subtract": [
                      "$$el.value",
                      {
                        "$let": {
                          "vars": {
                            "nextElement": {
                              "$arrayElemAt": [
                                "$time_series",
                                {
                                  "$add": [
                                    "$$el.index",
                                    1
                                  ]
                                }
                              ]
                            }
                          },
                          "in": "$$nextElement.value"
                        }
                      }
                    ]
                  },
                  -1
                ]
              }
            }
          },
          "as": "item",
          "cond": {
            "$gte": [
              "$$item",
              0
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
])
```

---

Another option which I think is less efficient is perform a map/reduce operation on our collection using the [`map_reduce`](http://api.mongodb.com/python/current/api/pymongo/collection.html#pymongo.collection.Collection.map_reduce) method.

```
>>> import pymongo
>>> from bson.code import Code
>>> client = pymongo.MongoClient()
>>> db = client.test
>>> collection = db.collection
>>> mapper = Code("""
...               function() {
...                 var derivatives = [];
...                 for (var index=1; index<this.time_series.length; index++) {
...                   derivatives.push(this.time_series[index] - this.time_series[index-1]);
...                 }
...                 emit(this._id, derivatives);
...               }
...               """)
>>> reducer = Code("""
...                function(key, value) {}
...                """)
>>> for res in collection.map_reduce(mapper, reducer, out={'inline': 1})['results']:
...     print(res)  # or do something with the document.
... 
{'value': [10.0, 20.0, 30.0, 40.0], '_id': ObjectId('57c11ddbe860bd0b5df6bc64')}
```

---

You can also retrieve all the document and use the `numpy.diff` to return the derivative like this:

```
import numpy as np


for document in collection.find({}, {'time_series': 1}):
    result = np.diff(document['time_series'])
```

Answer (score 4):

it's a bit dirty, but perhaps something like this?

```
use test_db
db['data'].remove({})
db['data'].insert({id: 1, time_series: [10,20,40,70,110]})

var mapF = function() {
    emit(this.id, this.time_series);
    emit(this.id, this.time_series);
};

var reduceF = function(key, values){
    var n = values[0].length;
    var ret = [];
    for(var i = 0; i < n-1; i++){
        ret.push( values[0][i+1] - values[0][i] );
    }
    return {'gradient': ret};
};

var finalizeF = function(key, val){
    return val.gradient;
}

db['data'].mapReduce(
    mapF,
    reduceF,
    { out: 'data_d1', finalize: finalizeF }
)

db['data_d1'].find({})
```

The "strategy" here is to emit the data to be operated on twice so that it is accessible in the reduce stage, return an object to avoid the message *"reduce -> multiple not supported yet"* and then filter back the array in the finalizer.

This script then produces:

```
MongoDB shell version: 3.2.9
connecting to: test
switched to db test_db
WriteResult({ "nRemoved" : 1 })
WriteResult({ "nInserted" : 1 })
{
    "result" : "data_d1",
        "timeMillis" : 13,
        "counts" : {
            "input" : 1,
            "emit" : 2,     
            "reduce" : 1,           
            "output" : 1                    
        },                                      
        "ok" : 1                                    
}                                                   
{ "_id" : 1, "value" : [ 10, 20, 30, 40 ] }         
bye
```

Alternatively, one could move all the processing into the finalizer (`reduceF` is not called here since `mapF` is assumed to emit unique keys):

```
use test_db
db['data'].remove({})
db['data'].insert({id: 1, time_series: [10,20,40,70,110]})

var mapF = function() {
    emit(this.id, this.time_series);
};

var reduceF = function(key, values){
};

var finalizeF = function(key, val){
    var x = val;
    var n = x.length;

    var ret = [];
    for(var i = 0; i < n-1; i++){
        ret.push( x[i+1] - x[i] );
    }
    return ret;
}

db['data'].mapReduce(
    mapF,
    reduceF,
    { out: 'data_d1', finalize: finalizeF }
)

db['data_d1'].find({})
```