# Cumulative SUM with MongoDB 4.2

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I am using MongoDB 4.2, the collection is the following:

```
{ "_id" : 1, "group_id": 1, "amount" : 10 }
{ "_id" : 2, "group_id": 1, "amount" : -5 }
{ "_id" : 3, "group_id": 1, "amount" : 8 }
{ "_id" : 4, "group_id": 2, "amount" : -1 }
{ "_id" : 5, "group_id": 2, "amount" : 7 }
{ "_id" : 6, "group_id": 2, "amount" : -2 }
{ "_id" : 7, "group_id": 3, "amount" : 10 }
{ "_id" : 8, "group_id": 3, "amount" : 15 }
```

How can i create a running sum of the documents?

**EXPECTED RESULT:**

**Note1 :** 
The documents must be filtered by **_id** giving a range for example `between _id:2 and _id:7`.

The result should be the following:

```
{ "_id" : 2, "group_id": 1, "total_amount" : -5 }
{ "_id" : 3, "group_id": 1, "total_amount" : 3 }   // (it was 8 but summing the previous -5 + 8 (current) = 3
{ "_id" : 4, "group_id": 2, "total_amount" : -1 }
{ "_id" : 5, "group_id": 2, "total_amount" : 6 }   // (it was 7 but summing the previous -1 + 7 = 6
{ "_id" : 6, "group_id": 2, "total_amount" : 4 }   // (it was -2 but summing the previous 6 - 2 = 4
{ "_id" : 7, "group_id": 3, "total_amount" : 10 }
```

**Note2:** 
The running sum must deal with `group_id` and sort by `_id` (the sort is important for summing of course)
I should only sum documents with the same `group_id` (ordered by _id)

Comment: Looks like https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38957649/compute-first-order-derivative-with-mongodb-aggregation-framework. Although I there are better way to do this today.

Comment: @styvane Can you explain? what are the other ways?